# NullPointer with Geocoder/AsyncTask - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-geocoder

I have what seems like should be an easy find, but I'm looking at all my variables and can't find the null value. I recently separated the `MyGeocoderTask` class out of `LocationMain`, which is probably where I messed things up. It worked fine before. :( Now when I click the button which activates `findThroughPopup()`, the app crashes. I'm still not completely a pro at getting variables to transfer over to other classes when needed, so besides finding which one is null, I should probably have help coding it right too. My two classes and stacktrace below. Thanks for your help.

**LocationMain.java**

```
package org.azurespot.practiceapp.location;

import org.azurespot.practiceapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class LocationMain extends Activity {

    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;

    protected static Double latitude;
    protected static Double longitude;
    protected static Context context;
    protected static EditText addressInput;

    protected LatLng myPosition;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_main);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    }

    // locates the user's location
    public void findMe(View v){

        if (LocationFragment.mMap == null){
            LocationFragment.setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        if (LocationFragment.mMap != null) {

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        LocationFragment.mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                                        getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        LocationFragment.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position
                                                (myPosition).title("Start"));

        // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
        LocationFragment.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom
                (new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 12.0f));
        }
    }

    // enter address of your choosing into the Dialog box
    public void findThroughPopup(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // set title
        builder.setTitle("Enter an address");

        // set EditText into your dialog box layout, using FrameLayout
        final FrameLayout frameView = new FrameLayout(this);
        builder.setView(frameView);
        // must inflate EditText separately
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = alertDialog.getLayoutInflater();
        View etView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_edit_text, frameView);
        // initialize EditText, use etView to pull from its specific XML
        addressInput = (EditText)etView.findViewById(R.id.address_field);

        // set Find button that finds address by showing on map
        builder.setPositiveButton("Find", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                // go through map setup if needed, otherwise process address input
                if (LocationFragment.mMap == null){

                    LocationFragment.setUpMapIfNeeded();
                }

                if (LocationFragment.mMap != null) {

                    String userLocale = addressInput.getText().toString();
                    if(userLocale!=null && !userLocale.equals("")){
                        new MyGeocoderTask().execute(userLocale); 
                    }
                }
                // zooms in to wherever you map ends up,
                // the 15f is in a range of 2.0 - 21.0
                CameraUpdate camZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12f);
                LocationFragment.mMap.animateCamera(camZoom);
            }
        });

        // set Cancel button
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // put all your builders in one create command
        alertDialog = builder.create();

        // show the dialog box
        alertDialog.show();

    } // end findThroughPopup()

    // resets map when back button is pressed
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            LocationFragment.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

**MyGeocoderTask.java**

```
package org.azurespot.practiceapp.location;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/***An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service****/

public class MyGeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

    protected LatLng enteredAddress;
    protected MarkerOptions markerOptions;


    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(LocationMain.context);
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    // part of the GeocoderTask life cycle
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(LocationMain.context, "No Location found", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        LocationFragment.mMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            enteredAddress = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
            address.getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(enteredAddress);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            LocationFragment.mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                LocationFragment.mMap.animateCamera
                        (CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(enteredAddress));
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
12-29 22:55:00.444: D/AbsListView(20174): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-29 22:55:06.154: W/dalvikvm(20174): threadid=24: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41737da0)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174): Process: org.azurespot.practiceapp, PID: 20174
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:95)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at org.azurespot.practiceapp.location.MyGeocoderTask.doInBackground(MyGeocoderTask.java:26)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at org.azurespot.practiceapp.location.MyGeocoderTask.doInBackground(MyGeocoderTask.java:1)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-29 22:55:06.154: E/AndroidRuntime(20174):    ... 4 more
12-29 22:55:06.164: D/AbsListView(20174): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-29 22:55:06.164: E/ViewRootImpl(20174): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-29 22:55:06.374: D/AbsListView(20174): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-29 22:55:06.784: D/AbsListView(20174): onDetachedFromWindow
12-29 22:55:06.784: D/AbsListView(20174): unregisterIRListener() is called 
12-29 22:55:07.524: I/Process(20174): Sending signal. PID: 20174 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be `LocationMain.context=null` in `MyGeocoderTask` as per your code.

So you probably pass context as a `Constructor` in your `MyGeocoderTask` like so

```
private Context mainContxt;

public MyGeocoderTask(Context con){
mainContxt=com;
}
```

and used like

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mainContxt);
```

and called from `Activity` like

```
 new MyGeocoderTask(your_Activity.this).execute(userLocale);
```

### Update:

```
 new MyGeocoderTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(userLocale);
```

Comment: Thanks MD, I tried your suggestion but still getting the same error. It could very well have something to do with context, because when `MyGeocoderTask` was still inside of `LocationMain`, it used `getBaseContext()` instead, and I changed it once I put it in its own class, but only because it had a red error on it and I didn't really know what to change it to, so whatever is used in place of `context` is a guess.

Comment: @NoniA. Try `getApplicationContext()` at `new MyGeocoderTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(userLocale)`

Comment: That totally worked, thanks so much!!! But can you explain why it worked? I have probably read those different forms of `context` many times, but they don't really sink in. :/

Comment: @NoniA. You need to play with `current Context`. That's it.

Comment: What is current Context? I haven't heard of that.

Comment: @NoniA. It means just a `Context`. You'll create Object of Android Classes only by using `Context`.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I just don't know why one works over the other. Like why would `LocationMain.this` not work, but `getApplicationContext()` works? Also, if you update your answer I will make it as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem is likely that Location.context is null as MD suggested and supported by the error chain starting with

```
 at org.azurespot.practiceapp.location.MyGeocoderTask.doInBackground(MyGeocoderTask.java:26
```

which I think is here, right?

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(LocationMain.context);
```

I didn't see anywhere in your code where you assigned LocationMain.context, but perhpas I missed something, 
But I would have thought you coudl solve this pretty easily by just adding

```
Location.context = this.getApplicationContext():
```

somewhere in either onResume() or in your onCreate().

Comment: Thanks for explaining, although MD did solve it first so I will make his as the answer, but I like your details, they did really add to an understanding. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did use `LocationMain.context`, hoping that it would choose the `context` of `LocationMain`, but I guess that was not correct code. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: Yeah, you were referring to the static variable context which you declared, but never assigned.

Comment: So assigning it means, declaring it in a constructor?

Comment: You've already declared it in the line:  protected static Context context;  but you never assigned it value.  Somehwere before you call the task you need to ass that variable 'context' you declared there with a value -- the current application context.  You can do that in one of the lifecycle methods like onCreate or onResume.  Otherwise its just null.  You could also pass it when you make the call into the async task, but I was jsut following the way you were doing it your code, which is calling the static class variable which would also work, had it been assigned the value.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining. I always thought declaring it meant it would "do its thing" in the code, like it was an automatic keyword in a sense (even though I know it's not a keyword). Really good info, thanks again!